# Unmet dependencies for the last version of npm (and node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, dependencies, npm

I have the last version of npm and node. And I have this errors/warnings:

```
$ npm --version
2.4.1

$ node --version
v0.10.36

$ npm install

> my_project@0.0.0 preinstall /Users/alex/Documents/projects/ruby/my_project
> script/gem_npm install

npm WARN package.json karma-ie-launcher@0.1.5 No README data
npm WARN package.json karma-qunit@0.1.4 No README data
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/alex/Documents/projects/ruby/my_project/node_modules/node-sass requires mkdirp@'~0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/alex/Documents/projects/ruby/my_project/node_modules/mkdirp,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/alex/Documents/projects/ruby/my_project/node_modules/testem requires js-yaml@'~0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/alex/Documents/projects/ruby/my_project/node_modules/js-yaml,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.2.5
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/alex/Documents/projects/ruby/my_project/node_modules/testem requires glob@'~3.1.21' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/alex/Documents/projects/ruby/my_project/node_modules/glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.2.11
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/alex/Documents/projects/ruby/my_project/node_modules/karma requires glob@'~3.1.21' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/alex/Documents/projects/ruby/my_project/node_modules/glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.2.11
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/alex/Documents/projects/ruby/my_project/node_modules/karma requires lodash@'~1.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/alex/Documents/projects/ruby/my_project/node_modules/lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.4.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/alex/Documents/projects/ruby/my_project/node_modules/karma-coffee-preprocessor/node_modules/coffee-script requires mkdirp@'~0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/alex/Documents/projects/ruby/my_project/node_modules/mkdirp,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.0
```

How can I resolve them?

Answer (score 1):

remove the node_modules folder

```
rm -rf node_modules/
```

Run `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

This a known issue with the dependency resolution of npm being a bit broken, see here: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/1341#issuecomment-20634338

The easiest resolution is manually installing dependencies, or structuring your package.json such that any top-level modules that are also dependencies of other modules are listed before the dependant model.

e.g: `npm install mkdirp@'~0.3.5'` as extracted from your log.